# Reload a page in javscript to a specific controller's Action Method with parameter in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, client-side

I have been trying in JavaScript to reload a page to particular controller's action method with a parameter but getting error.

My output works when I use

```
 window.location.reload(true);
```

But I want to redirect to controller's action method with PARAM's value and I am trying this

```
// Gives me the value in a function
var supId = data.supplierId;
//redirects the page so the I can see the updated the data
window.location.reload= '@Url.Action("GetSupplier", "Supplier", new { supplierId = supId })';
```

But it is also not working for me.

Can some one tell me what should I do

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this ,

```
var supId = data.supplierId;
window.location.href = '/Supplier/GetSupplier/' + supId ;
```